# Can't style body in style.css (Node.js)

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, mean-stack

I just got a basic Node.js site up and running but am running into some strange problem. Using the style.css stylesheet that comes by default when using Express, I attempt to style the body but it doesn't seem to recognize it. The only solution seems to be adding class `body` to the actual body and changing the css declaration to `.body`. Why does the below code not work?

style.css

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <% include partials/head %>
  </head>
  <body>
     <% include partials/nav %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1><%= title %></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% include partials/footer %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the element to see what style it's getting and from where?

Comment: @Waxi I believe that would solve it. Seems that bootstrap is overriding the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap was overriding the css in my custom file. Simply putting the custom css file declaration after the Bootstrap declaration fixed it and allowed me to override Bootstrap css styles.

Before

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title><%= title %> | NodeSite</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Core CSS -->
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title><%= title %> | NodeSite</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Core CSS -->
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```